# How can I position the font awesome expanded menu indicator directly next to the menu text?

Tags: css

Working on this site:
https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/

Trying to get the font awesome arrow to the right of the menu nav items (which indicates there are sub-pages) to show up immediately to the right of the text instead of with a giant space in between text and arrow.

Would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest using a wrapper element that contains both the FA arrow and the text, and then move some of your sizing to that wrapper element (also make taht the one that turns orange when you hover). Then inside, you can get rid of the display:block's and position:absolutes. Probably a better way, but I'm not a CSS guru

Comment: FYI you can improve future questions by creating a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as opposed to linking us to an offsite page.

Comment: I was able to get it moved in, but then I lost the mouse over highlight of the entire block, it just highlighted the word. I imagine I did something wrong. For now, since I'm short on time, I wimped out and found another icon to put below the text instead of to the right while I try to get your suggestions working. Obviously I'm a CSS noob :p We are an all volunteer organization; unfortunately I'm the best we've got, so I got the job. I enjoy learning more about it though, so I will definitely spend some more time on this as soon as I can. Thanks for the help - my google-fu was failing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, this is how you would do it:

Step 1: in the following CSS rule, change the `display` value to `inline-block`.

```
.WaGadgetMenuHorizontal .menuInner ul.firstLevel > li > .item > a {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: top;
white-space: nowrap;
position: relative;
font: normal 18px/26px Oswald, Helvetica, sans-serif;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Step 2: In the following rule, change the right-padding to 15px (the second value in the `padding` rule).

```
.WaGadgetMenuHorizontal.menuStyle004 .menuInner ul.firstLevel > li > .item > a > span {
 padding: 15px 15px 15px 10px;
 ...
 }
```

Step 3: In the following, change the `right` offset to `0` (or equivalently `0px`).

```
.WaGadgetMenuHorizontal .menuInner ul.firstLevel > li.dir > .item > a::after {
content: "\f107";
font-family: FontAwesome;
color: white;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: 15px;
right: 0px;
}
```

I am assuming that you have access to all the CSS stylesheets in your content management system (web builder platform).

If not, you need to add these rules to override the pre-existing rules, so you need to learn how to do that first.  You may need to get help from the tech support people where you are hosting.

**Note:** I went to your website using Firefox and I inspected the various elements and tried out these three steps and that did the trick.  Make sure
to check out the other major browsers (Chrome and IE).

Keep in mind that these changes will change the overall look of the navigation so you may have other visual side effects that may not be suitable for your design.

**Aside:** the HTML in questions looks like the following (I omitted a few wrapping `div`'s):

```
<ul style="" class="firstLevel">
  <li class="sel">
    <div class="item"><a href="https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/" title="Home"><span>Home</span></a></div>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <div class="item"> <a href="https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/Coop" title="Coop"><span>Coop</span></a> </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">
    <div class="item"><a href="https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/Resource-Center" title="Resource Center"><span>Resource Center</span></a>
      <ul class="secondLevel">
        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item"><a href="https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/page-1075491" title="Home (Demo)"><span>Home (Demo)</span></a></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <div class="item"> <a href="https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/Events" title="Events"><span>Events</span></a> </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">
    <div class="item"> <a href="https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/About-Us" title="About Us"><span>About Us</span></a>
      <ul class="secondLevel">
        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item"> <a href="https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/Donate" title="Donate"><span>Donate</span></a> </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="last-child">
    <div class="item"> <a href="https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/Volunteer" title="Volunteer"><span>Volunteer</span></a> </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i restructured so that it works but you have to adapt it to your case

```css
.dir {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  }
.item {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  }
a {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  }
a:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
span {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
span:after {
  content:"<";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  }
```

```html
<li class="dir">
 <div class="item">
  <a href="https://voyagers.wildapricot.org/Resource-Center" title="Resource Center">
          <span>Resource Center</span>
      </a>
</div>
</li>
```